# Changing max node capacity in M-tree affects the results

Tags: scala, search, tree

Posting the code for the entire tree for this problem would be pointless (too long and chaotic), and I've tried to fix this problem for a while now, so I don't really want some concrete solution, but more like ideas as to why this might be happening. So:

- I have a dataset of 1.000.000 coordinates and I insert them into the tree. I do a range search after and for `MaxCapacity=10` I get the correct results (and for any number >= 10). If I switch to `MaxCapacity=4` results are wrong. But if I shrink the dataset to about 20.000 coordinates the results are again correct for `MaxCapacity=4`.

So to me, this looks like an incorrect split algorithm and it just shows for small MaxCapacities and large datasets where we have an enormous amount of splits. But the algorithm checks out for almost everything so I can't really find a mistake there. Any other ideas? Tree is written in SCALA, promotion policy promotes the two points that are the furthest away from each other and for split policy we iterate through the entries of the overflown node and we put each entry into the group of the promoted point that is closer to.

Comment: Your guess about an "incorrect split" looks reasonable. I am afraid providing any advice without seeing the code is very hard and I doubt you will get any useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if anyone will be interested in this but I found the reasons causing this. I thought the problem was in split but I was wrong. The problem was when I was choosing in the Insert Recursion algorithm what node to jump to next in order to place the entry. So I was choosing this node by calculating the distance between each node's center and the entry's point. The node with minimum said distance was chosen.
This works fine if the entry happens to reside inside the radius of multiple nodes. In this case the minDistance works as intended but if the entry doesn't reside in any node's radius? In this case we would have to expand the radius as well to contain the entry. So we would need to find the node whose radius would expand less if it were to include the entry into its children. For a node, its distance from the entry point might be minimum but the expansion needed might be catastrophically big. I had not considered this case and as a result entries were placed in wrong nodes, causing huge expansions, causing huge overlaps. When I implemented this case the problem was fixed!